# Counting SUM(VALUE) from previous cell

Tags: sql, sum

I have the following table:

| A | Sum(Tickets) |
| --- | --- |
| 01-2022 | 5 |
| 02-2022 | 2 |
| 03-2022 | 8 |
| 04-2022 | 1 |
| 05-2022 | 3 |
| 06-2022 | 3 |
| 07-2022 | 4 |
| 08-2022 | 1 |
| 09-2022 | 5 |
| 10-2022 | 5 |
| 11-2022 | 3 |

I would like to create the following extra column 'TotalSum(Tickets)' but I am stuck....
Anyone who can help out?

| A | Sum(Tickets) | TotalSum(Tickets) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-2022 | 5 | 5 |
| 02-2022 | 2 | 7 |
| 03-2022 | 8 | 15 |
| 04-2022 | 1 | 16 |
| 05-2022 | 3 | 19 |
| 06-2022 | 3 | 22 |
| 07-2022 | 4 | 26 |
| 08-2022 | 1 | 27 |
| 09-2022 | 5 | 32 |
| 10-2022 | 5 | 37 |
| 11-2022 | 3 | 40 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

left join the same table where date is not bigger, then sum that for every date:

```
select 
    table1.date, 
    sum(t.tickets) 
from 
    table1 
        left join table1 t 
        on  t.date<= table1.date 
group by
    table1.date;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `SUM()` as a window function here:

```sql
SELECT A, SumTickets, SUM(SumTickets) OVER (ORDER BY A) AS TotalSumTickets
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY A;
```

But this assumes that you actually have a bona-fide column `SumTickets` which contains the sums.  Assuming you really showed us the intermediate result of some aggregation query, you should use:

```sql
SELECT A, SUM(Tickets) AS SumTickets,
          SUM(SUM(Tickets)) OVER (ORDER BY A) AS TotalSumTickets
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY A
ORDER BY A;
```

Comment: @bbpeterson: the window function solution, as demonstrated here, is more efficient than the other solution using a self-join, which requires scanning the table twice (vs only one scan with window functions).